# how does procrun execute a jvm.dll?

Tags: java, dll, jvm, procrun

According to the [procrun documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html), procrun can run in 'jvm mode' where it will "start Java in-process".

Does that mean that procrun.exe itself loads jvm.dll, and then calls an entry point? If so, then 1) what is the entry point? 2) wouldn't the "java.exe" executable have code which is different per version of java and wouldn't that be information that procrun.exe would need? so how is it feasible to just skip running java.exe and go straight to the dll?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503327/difference-between-java-exe-javaw-exe-and-jvm-dll), java.exe really is only a thin wrapper to call `jvm.dll` (which any other process can include as well). It is true that `java.exe` is different sizes for each JRE version, but that must be immaterial in the end.

However, I do not know the entry point for jvm.dll. (but I would accept the answer of someone who does).