# Difference between JVM, server/jvm.dll file and Java HotSpot VM both client and server versions

Tags: java, virtual-machine, jvm-hotspot

Can someone please explain me the difference between JVM, server\jvm.dll file and Java HotSpot VM. I have already studied

jvm.dll file from [Difference between java.exe, javaw.exe and jvm.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503327/difference-between-java-exe-javaw-exe-and-jvm-dll) and

HotSpot from [Difference between JVM and HotSpot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568253/difference-between-jvm-and-hotspot)

[Real differences between "java -server" and "java -client"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html#solid

but still didn't understand the concept. Please give a simple and clear explanation.

Comment: You couldn't understand what it is from 4 different sources, why do you think you'll understand it from here? I think you didn't _actually_ study those.

Comment: may be you could give a better explanation in simple words

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between java.exe, javaw.exe and jvm.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503327/difference-between-java-exe-javaw-exe-and-jvm-dll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.exe` is the Java *launcher*. It's a very small program that loads `jvm.dll`, and uses JNI (Java Native Interface, an interface inside `jvm.dll` that is used to connect C and Java code) to start up the JVM.

The difference between the client and server versions is in the warmup time and optimisation strategy (client takes less time to start up than server, but performs less optimisations). So `-server` is generally better for long-running processes, where the longer startup time is amortised, and `-client` is generally better for short-lived ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what is HotSpot VM and how it is different from JVM ?

Comment: @user3519914 HotSpot is the implementation of the JVM that comes with OpenJDK and Oracle JDK. Other Java implementations (e.g., IBM, Harmony, etc.) use different JVM implementations.

Comment: ya exactly what is the meaning of JVM implementation?
And where is jvm.dll loaded?

Comment: @user3519914 The JVM is defined in the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html). Any software which implements what that document says is a compliant JVM implementation. HotSpot is one such implementation.