# is it possible to execute a jar file using jvm.dll. instead of java.exe?

Tags: java

I have a installer with a JRE embebed, that is, it have a jvm.dll instead a java.exe. What i would like to do is to execute a Java app (a jar file) using jvm.dll instead of java.exe.

Is it that possible?

Comment: Without further information on what you have, check this https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html

Comment: My Java program is a Websocket server program deployed as a jar file. I can run this program like this java -jar myserver.jar, that is, using java.exe. The problem is that myserver.jar is installed with a installer in windows (.exe) and this installer also install a embebed JRE. This embebed JRE does not have java.exe. Instead it has dlls like jvm.dll. java.exe is a wrapper of jvm.dll. What I woul like is to execute myserver.jar using this jvm.dll distribute with my installer instead of using the JRE installed in the diferents computers.

Comment: What installer is that? Is it a custom one or something like javapackager?

Comment: It is a custom one, using Inno Setup : http://www.jrsoftware.org/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

You have to write C/C++ program to achieve it (or in other language able to do native calls).

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible, unless you don't embed your java application in a C++ application.

Further reading:

[Difference between java.exe, javaw.exe and jvm.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503327/difference-between-java-exe-javaw-exe-and-jvm-dll)

[Embed Java into a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506329/embed-java-into-a-c-application)

Comment: Well then it's possible then, isnt it?

Comment: Yes but only if you embed your application into a C++ program. You cannot execute a java program using jvm.dll only