# How does JetBrains create .exe files for their IDE's?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

So as far as I'm aware, JetBrains mostly uses Java (swing) for their IDE's.

But I noticed all their IDE's have a .exe, so I was wondering, where/how does their JDK gets executed. Especially since the JDK is not even showing up in the task manager.

I tried myself to create a exe and start the JDK as subprocess but even then the task manger does show the JDK running as separate app.

How are they doing it did they modify the JDK to achieve this?

Comment: If you ask this question in Jetbrain forum, probably they may answer, by the way what do you want to do? Do you want to achieve something like this ?

Comment: I'm working on a JavaFX application and yea I want to achieve the same. No IDE but I wan't to have a exe have it show up right in the taskmanager and yea maybe there are some other things I  didn't even consider yet.

Comment: Not sure what JetBrains does, but you can use [`jpackage`](https://jdk.java.net/jpackage/) (currently early-access).

Comment: I suspect they have a native executable written in C which dynamically links to jvm.dll. This is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503327/difference-between-java-exe-javaw-exe-and-jvm-dll/8503524).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193723/discussion-between-slaw-and-natschz).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA based products use the [custom launcher](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/980129c6eaf755043574d138869c7a28dd935922/native/WinLauncher/WinLauncher.cpp) to load the JVM on Windows. It's open source and you can investigate how it works by analyzing the **WinLauncher** source code in the GitHub repository. It loads `jvm.dll` dynamically.

Many years ago we used a third-party solution ([EXE4J](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files)), but switched to the custom launcher for more flexibility and to make IntelliJ IDEA Community 100% open source.

Comment: Direct Link to source file:
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/980129c6eaf755043574d138869c7a28dd935922/native/WinLauncher/WinLauncher.cpp